# Outlook (2013, 2016) IMAP: STORE FLAGS

Tags: outlook, imap, categories, flags

In the work we actively use IMAP flags (user-defined, for example: FIRSTCLASS) with Thunderbird client. But now we need to move to Outlook (reason: better search engine, although Thunderbird will be always in my heart).
Unfortunately Outlook doesn't support IMAP STORE command for flags. ([RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.6))
How I can change this behavior? For example with Outlook VSTO. Or COM add-in?
I just need at least a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. And categories do not work with IMAP4 accounts either - see http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/outlook-categories-flags-and-imap-accounts/

Under PST with POP3/SMTP the categories will work.

Comment: 'The IMAP protocol doesn’t support the Category and Flag properties on messages and assigned categories and flags are not synced back to the IMAP server.'

It's not really true. IMAP can store information about custom flags (labels in Thunderbird). So in theory it can be mapped to Categories.

Comment: But Outlook doesn't support that,. probably because the actual implementation details differ between different servers.

Comment: In IMAP RFC (3501) it's describe in 2.3.2: "A keyword is defined by the server implementation.  Keywords do not
   begin with "\".  Servers MAY permit the client to define new keywords
   in the mailbox (see the description of the PERMANENTFLAGS response
   code for more information)."
Can I talk with server by IMAP under Outlook instance and change mail attribute - Categories in visual interface?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm sorry for my perseverance but I really want understand why It's not possible or find a way. Maybe I cant change how Outlook talks by IMAP. But maybe I can force outlook get additional info for every message using FETCH FLAGS command.

Comment: You cannot change the way Outlook IMAP4 store works unless you develop a complete store replacement - this is as Extended MAPI as it gets...